# Angular 12 FormsModule two way binding retains information

Tags: angular

Currently, I'm going through the tutorial heroes for angular 12.0.4 (https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2). When I start with two-way binding forms I run into the following problem:

1. I click on a Hero, making it selected
2. I change the name (works with 2-way binding in FormsModule)
3. I click on the next hero, changing the selected Hero
4. The next heroes name changes to the one I selected earlyer, losing it's original 'name' data

Is this a bug or how should I otherwise fix my code? Thanks in advance for the advice. I have a gif of the workflow here: [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQbdK.gif)

The problem arises on Ubuntu in WSL with google Chrome. I cannot reproduce this error in stackblitz with the exact same code. The issue also does not happen in Edge.

heroes.compontent.html:

```html
<table class='table table-hover'>
    <thead>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col">Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
            <tr (click)="onSelect(hero)" [class.table-active]="hero === selectedHero">
                <th scope="row">{{hero.id}}</th>
                <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
            </tr>
        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div *ngIf="selectedHero">

    <h2>{{selectedHero.name | uppercase}} Details</h2>
    <div><span>id: </span>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
    <div>
      <label for="hero-name">Hero name: </label>
      <input id="hero-name" [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name">
    </div>
  
  </div>
```

heroes.component.ts:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.scss']
})
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes: Hero[] = [
    { id: 11, name: 'Dr Nice' },
    { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
    { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
    { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
    { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
    { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
    { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
    { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
    { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
    { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
  ];
  selectedHero?: Hero;
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

}
```

hero.ts:

```js
export interface Hero {
    id: number;
    name: string;
  }
```

Comment: Tried reproducing your code on a Stackblitz, but can't seem to reproduce this behaviour?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pqvcut?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Odd, when I put all my code there I also cant reproduce it. (https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bug-heroes-t) Maybe it's an error on the client side with npm...

Comment: Hard to say, I guess. Your code looks correct as is as well... :)

Answer (score 1):

The bug was fixed in Angular v 12.0.5